# pandas dataframe giving empty frame when variable is used to filter

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I need to filter it. And I am using

```
for i in values:
  df = df[df['name'] == i]
  print(df)
```

Here I am getting empty dataframe. But if I use `df = df[df['name'] == 'manualentryofname']` its ok. But `values` is a list of names based on which I need to filter the dataframe and do some operations.

Comment: for loop is not only to filter..i have some operation under this based on i value of for loop

Comment: And to your question, if `values` contains `name` it should working.

Comment: because after first iteration it will contain only first i value, after second iteration it will return you empty dataframe

Comment: if you want to keep only value in values list then go with @zipa solution, and if you really want to use in loop then dont store the intermediate result in df again, keep  intermediate result in temp valriable then  try to append next interation result, it should work

Answer (score 1):

If you only wish to **extract** rows of your dataframe relating to each `name` where `name` is in `values`, you can use `groupby` after a filter:

```
for key, df_key in df[df['name'].isin(values)].groupby('name'):
    # read dataframe extract in df_key
```

If you wish to **modify** parts of your dataframe depending on `name`, you can use a mask within a `for` loop:

```
for key in values:

    # calculate Boolean series mask
    mask = df['name'] == key

    # perform manipulations based on Boolean series
    df.loc[mask, 'some_col'] *= 2
    df.loc[mask, 'some_other_col'] += 1
```

An optimal solution will be highly dependent on the nature of the manipulations. The above example manipulations, for example, are vectorisable and do not require an explicit `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
df.loc[df['name'].isin(values)]
```

Comment: for loop is not only to filter..i have some operation under this based on i value of for loop

Comment: @qwww Okay, can you share example of input and desired output so I could help you further?

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this if you really need to work with loop, otherwise go with zipa's solution. It will append filtered result from original and appended in another temp.

```
temp=pd.DataFrame()
for i in values:
  temp = temp.append(df[df['name'] == i])
```